# Solving an SDE - tips and tricks

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the stochastic differential equation

$$ dX_t = \ln(1 + X^2_t)\space dt + X^+_tdB_t $$

with $X_0 = a$ and $x^+ = \max({x, 0})$ is the positive part of real number $x$, and $a$ is a real constant.

I have no idea how to even approach solving this SDE. Are there any general tricks to use when given a new SDE?

Comment: I don't know if you can use it to solve your particular problem but the last 15 or so pages of this document look useful at a glance. https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2019/REUPapers/Liu,Shuhong.pdf